# How do I find next multiple of 1000 days and the corresponding date?

Tags: c#, date

I have to make a program that asks someone for their birthday and calculates when the next day is when they turn a multiple of 1000 days.

I made the following code already:

```
using System;
Console.WriteLine("welkom bij de verKdag calculator, vul de volgende getallen in:");
Console.WriteLine("wat is je geboortedag? ");
String s = Console.ReadLine();
int d = int.Parse(s);
Console.WriteLine("wat is je geboortemaand");
int m = int.Parse( Console.ReadLine() );
Console.WriteLine("wat is je geboortejaar");
int y = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
DateTime gebdat = new DateTime(y, m, d);
DateTime vandaag = DateTime.Today;
var diffofdates = vandaag.Subtract(gebdat);
Console.WriteLine(diffofdates);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Now< I need to figure out a way to find the closest multiple of 1000 to `diffofdates` and calculate which date corresponds to that, how do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [modulus operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#remainder-operator-) to calculate the number of days remaining, and then use that to get the target date:

```
int daysRemaining = 1000 - (int)diffofdates.TotalDays % 1000;
DateTime targetDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(daysRemaining);

Console.WriteLine("You'll reach a multiple of 1000 days " + 
    $"on {targetDate.ToShortDateString()} (in {daysRemaining} days from now)");
```

As a side note, consider using `int.TryParse()` instead of `int.Parse()` and validating that the user input is a valid date. Alternatively, you could use `DateTime.TryParse()` or (preferably) `DateTime.TryParseExact()` and allow the user to enter their date of birth in one go.